# LaTeX table formatter extension in VSCode

Tags: tables, visual-studio-code

Is there any latex extension similar to the Markdown Table extension for VSCode that can automagically format your tex tables in a nice way?

For example,

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
12 & 21412
& 12312412312 \\
656
& 23123 & 565645647 \\
\end{tabular}
```

becomes

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
12  & 21412 & 12312412312 \\
656 & 23123 &   565645647 \\
\end{tabular}
```

It would make altering data in already existing long tables so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The "Format Document" command with Latex Workshop installed does that for me.

It is accessible on Windows typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to access the Command Palette.

Comment: Could you please guide me where I can find this "Format Document" command? I couldn't find any command related to formatting under the TeX icon in the left sidebar. In the command palette, I tried invoking "Format Document" and also "Format Document With..." and then selecting "LaTeX Workshop", but none of these change anything. I have also tried setting {"editor.defaultFormatter": "James-Yu.latex-workshop"} in settings.json to no avail. It would be great if you could show some examples with images, if possible.

Comment: @vicky I use the Command Palette. On Windows, the shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+P